# How to store a value in one function and retrieve that value in another function

Tags: php, function

I'm trying to implement twitter like followers function in my website. I have a function like this in my plugin:

```
function current_profile_user_id() {
   return "current profile user id";
}
function button( $args = '' ) {
        $defaults = array(
            'leaderid'   => current_profile_user_id(),
            'followerid' => 'logged in user id'
        );
        return "HTML button";
    }
```

The only way I can pass the current profile user id value, its from the user profile page by using function arguments.

Let's say the `$currentuser->ID` returns the current profile page user value but this variable only available in the profile page.

Can anyone tell me how to pass that value to the function `current_profile_user_id()`, store that value and return the html button?

**Please note:** Many of my other functions too uses the value returned by `current_profile_user_id()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had better save the value in the session. A function may rely on the global scope, but that is not saved between pages.

You could do something like

```
function currentProfile($profile = False)
{
    if ($profile)
        $_SESSION['curr_profile'] = $profile;
    else
        if (isset($_SESSION['curr_profile']))
            return $_SESSION['curr_profile'];
    return $profile;
}

function current_profile_user_id()
{
    return currentProfile()->ID;
}
```

and then, as soon as you can, save the profile in session

```
currentProfile($currentuser);
```

...ought to work. This way, you can change the persistence of `curr_profile` if need be, without having to revisit all of your code.

### on a maybe-related note

*(Not being very clear on what you're attempting to do and how, I hope this may turn out to be useful)*

So you have a list of users and want to display a 'follow' template for each. The list of users is retrieved from some sort of database, so you'll have something like

```
while($user = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    // Populate the template

    // Append template to display code
}
```

In that template you will have something like:

```
<a href="follow.php?id={$user['id']}">Follow {$user['name']}</a>
```

or maybe an AJAX call to add that user to the logged user's follow-list without refreshing the page. Anyway, there will be a *server page* invoked, and that page will receive a *session cookie* and the ID the user selected.

So that page will have to note the new following/unfollowing, and it will have everything it needs to do so:

1. The ID of the user to be followed, in `$_REQUEST['id']`
2. All data of the follower, in `$_SESSION`.

It could then execute, for example, a query such as

```
 INSERT IGNORE INTO followers (follower, followee) VALUES ($id1, $id2);
```

to persist the information.

Comment: Hi thanks for the good answer. But if I use sessions don't you think i'll get problem when I list the users [like this page](http://demos.99points.info/digg_like_follow_unfollow/)

Comment: In that case you'd have the IDs embedded in the code, or they would be available in the code which generates each user "follow" block. Then the ID can be passed when you click on "follow", and the data recovered in the next page from the database.

Comment: Please forgive me. I'm a php noob. So its really hard to understand what you are saying without some sample code. It would be very nice if you can give me some sample code. Thanks

Comment: I'm not very clear on what exactly you want to do, and how your application is structured. I'll try and add some notes.

Comment: Let me explain my situation. I'm using wordpress. I would like to display follow button in each author page.  So the logged in user can follow the author. But I have problem in getting current displayed page author id. Please refer [line 117 of this file](https://gist.github.com/0a45271a0c7406f3e02f) which generates the button and the functions of [this file](https://gist.github.com/afc139eacf843b403194). You will understand what i'm talking. Thanks